# Merging data from multiple Lists, will it work post saving the Site as a Template?

Tags: list, site-template, merge

Planning to merge multiple columns data from 02 SPS lists running on SPS2013 through SPD2013, following article:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-data-from-multiple-sources-in-a-single-Data-View-f9898d20-a5ab-4973-9d16-9f4e4c088ae1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Any suggestion if the link merge will work even after saving the site as a template?

Such that creating the new site through the template, will have the merge link data source available.

Any pointer will be of great benefit.